# How to change SelectText in Gridview depending if there is a booking?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a grid view which displays information regarding a booking. I have a select column but would like to change the select text to "book" if there is no booking or "view" if there is a booking. Is this possible and if so could I be pointed in the right direction or be shown an example? I am using c# asp.net webforms in visual studio 2013.

Comment: what's seem to be the problem ?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Very new with gridview!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter the text of each cell in the event RowDataBound.

```
protected void gridview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    { 
         e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "WHATEVER TEXT YOU WANT";
    }
}
```